# Magento 2 how to create two controllers in the same module?

Tags: magento-2.0, third-party-module

I have created new module called 'Vendor/Modulename' in magento2. It is working fine. But i was unable to create a new custom controller and action in the same module.

Comment: can you paste the code of second controller that is not working ?

Answer (score 5):

> Namespace: Prince
>
> Module: Helloworld

**Create first index controller and index action**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "This is First Controller";
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Create second - second controller and index action**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Controller/second/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Controller\Second;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "This is second controller";
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Now add routes in routes.xml**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="Prince_Helloworld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Now run index controller and index action**

http://localhost/magento2/hello/index/index

**Now run second controller and index action**

http://localhost/magento2/hello/second/index